# Woocommerce WP_Query post__not_in problem

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to exclude sale products from output related products.

In `$args` i have field `post__not_in` where i want to output array of values from `wc_get_product_ids_on_sale();` function.

Code before `$args`

```
$related = $product->get_related( $posts_per_page );    
$product_ids_on_sale = wc_get_product_ids_on_sale();
```

After i wrote args

```
$args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
            'post_type'            => 'product',
            'ignore_sticky_posts'  => 1,
            'no_found_rows'        => 1,
            'posts_per_page'       => $posts_per_page,
            'orderby'              => $orderby,
            'post__in'             => $related,
            'post__not_in'         => $product_ids_on_sale,
        ) );
```

But in frontend i see products not in sale and in sale

I try to echo $product_ids_on_sale it returns `Array`
As i understand, i need to return each value from array `$product_ids_on_sale` separated with `,`
Than i try to write `foreach` like

```
$product_ids_on_sale = wc_get_product_ids_on_sale();
         foreach($product_ids_on_sale as $result) {
            echo $res,',';
        }
```

But echo is not i want. I need to `return` it
Also i try to write to 'post__not_in'

```
array_merge( array( 0 ), wc_get_product_ids_on_sale() )
```

Didn't help...

Please help me to exclude sale products!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have both `post__in` and `post__not_in` as input arguments for `WP_Query`, then only `post__in` is activated. See the source [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/7d34efea8d12d79604b6e192cd98b3b34a943d29/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L1963-L1972).

If you need to exclude IDs from the `post__in`, you should do it before passing on the array.